# Linear Operator Example

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Show that the linear operator defined by the equations 
>   \begin{align*}
> w_1 &= x_1 - 2x_2 +x_3\\ 
> w_2 &= 5x_1 - x_2 + 3x_3\\ 
> w_3 &= 4x_1 + x_2 +2x_3\\
> \end{align*}
>   is not onto $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Find a the relationship between $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_3$ to ensure the system is consistent and use it to find two vectors in the codomain that are in the range, and two that are not.

Okay, so I got everything except the last half. For the last part of the question, I am not exactly sure what to do but I think I get what they are asking: the "relationship" and how I will use that to find three vectors they ask for.

Anyway, I have proved that the columns of the standard matrix do not span $\mathbb{R}^3$ and therefore the linear transformation does not map onto $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

Focusing on the RHS, notice that the sum of the first and third  expressiongive you the second expressions.

Hence we required $w_1+w_3=w_2$. Try to prove that this condition is what we need.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

$$rk\left( \begin{matrix} 
1 & -2 & 1 \\
5 & -1 & 3 \\
4 & 1 & 2 
\end{matrix} \right) \stackrel{w_2 \rightarrow w_2-w_3}{=} rk\left( \begin{matrix} 
1 & -2 & 1 \\
1 & -2 & 1 \\
4 & 1 & 2 
\end{matrix} \right)\stackrel{w_1 \rightarrow w_1-w_2}{=} rk\left( \begin{matrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 1 \\
4 & 1 & 2 
\end{matrix} \right) = 2$$

Comment: what do r and k represent?

Comment: he uses $rk$ to denote rank.